# Skrollr relative top-bottom fires early in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have several relative positioned divs stacked on top of eachother with a height of 100% set with jQuery on load.
Inside each relative positioned div is a fixed div that holds the content.

As you scroll down the page I am using skrollr to animate the fixed divs top -100%.
My markup for skrollr is like this `data-anchor-target="#home" data-top="top:0%;"data-top-bottom="top:-100%;"` so when the parent slide is at the top of the viewport it is position top and when the bottom of the parent slide is at the top of the viewport it is top -100%. Right?

The second fixed position div is abit longer than the screen height so instead of making it top -100% it becomes position relative when the parent is at the top of the viewport. `data-100-top="position:fixed;" data-top='position:relative;'`

The third div follows the same logic as the first one `data-anchor-target="#exhibitions" data-top="top:0%;"data-top-bottom="top:-100%;"`

This all works fine in Firefox and IE but in Chrome and Safari the 3rd div starts animating too early. The fixed content is already half off the screen by the time the parent div is at the top, which confuses me because the data-top attribute is set to top:0;

Here is the example - http://dev.touch-akl.com/standout/

Link to Skrollr - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

HTML Example

```
<section id="home" class="page">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor-target="#home" data-top="top:0%;"data-top-bottom="top:-100%;">
        <section class="content">
             CONTENT GOES HERE
        </section>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="page">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor-target="#about" data-100-top="position:fixed;" data-top='position:relative;'>
        <section class="content">
             CONTENT GOES HERE - THIS IS THE ONE THAT IS HIGHER THAN THE OTHERS
        </section>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="exhibitions" class="page">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor-target="#exhibitions" data-top="top:0%;"data-top-bottom="top:-100%;">
        <section class="content">
             CONTENT GOES HERE - THIS IS THE ONE THAT TRIGGERS EARLY
        </section>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="events" class="page">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor-target="#events" data-top="top:0%;"data-top-bottom="top:-100%;">
        <section class="content">
             CONTENT GOES HERE
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in Chrome (Version 26.0.1410.63 on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally made a fix for this in jQuery, not sure what was wrong with the way before, now the data attribute for the scroll distance of the about slide is set in jQuery as pixels instead of a fixed percentage value in the HTML

```
    // check for desktop
    if($('body').hasClass('skrollr')){

        var $page = $('.page'),
            $slide = $('.slide');

        $slide.css({'position':'fixed'});

        $page.each(function(){

            var $this = $(this),
                $thisSlide = $this.find('.slide'),
                newHeight = $thisSlide.outerHeight();

            // if the slide contents height is less than the window height
            if(newHeight < winHeight){

                // set the height of the page and slide to the window height
                $this.add($thisSlide).css({'height':winHeight});

            }else{

                // set the height of the page and slide to the contents height
                $this.add($thisSlide).css({'height':newHeight});

                if($this.is("#about")){

                    $thisSlide.attr('data-300-top-bottom', 'top:'+ -newHeight +'px');    

                }   // if this slide was the about slide

            }   // end if this slide is smaller than the window height

        }); // end each page function

         s.refresh();  

    }   // end if was desktop
```